# .wav file in target folder modified after mvn clean install, won't play properly

Tags: java, maven, wav

I am working on a maven project and need to play a .wav file to accompany a desktop alert.  I have tested the .wav file on its own to make sure that it works and it does.  I have imported it into my project structure and when it is in the source directory, it is 46 KB.  When I perform mvn clean install on the project, the target directory that is generated contains the .wav file, but it is 87 kb there.

This is the error that I get:
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file

I put in a logging statement to check the generated path in my log4j logs and the path is correct.  This makes me think that the mvn clean install is modifying the format or contents of the .wav file, but I don't understand how and ultimately how to prevent it from happening.

**Update**

Here is a code snippet:

```
String filename = this.getClass().getResource("/audio/affirmative.wav").getPath();

logger.debug("wav file path: " + filename);

AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename).getAbsoluteFile());

Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start();
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wild guess: it reads it as text using some sort of `InputStreamReader` or such...

Comment: Where are you storing the wav? `src/main/resources`?

Comment: That is exactly where it's stored Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have put the wav file in a directory which gets filtered by Maven (variable replacement).

Solution: Put binary files in a directory which doesn't get filtered.

In my projects I started to have 2 resource directories:

- src/main/resources: filtered
- src/main/resources-bin: not filtered

You can have a look at the POM file I'm using as the parent POM here to see how to configure this:
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/softsmithy/softsmithy-parent/2.2/softsmithy-parent-2.2.pom

Or, if you like, you can use it as the parent of your own parent POM as well:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.softsmithy</groupId>
    <artifactId>softsmithy-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</parent>
```

Like this you will get the resource configuration and much more out of the box.

Make sure to override alle project specific settings in your parent POM, though.

You can check this by running `mvn help:effective-pom`.

Comment: Beat me do it. If `maven-resources-plugin` [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) is the culprit (second wild guess). Op can simple exclude binary extensions.